# Is there a way to re-intall Forefront Identity Manager?

Tags: user-profile, synchronisation, forefront

Is there a way to re-install the FIM for SP2010? I think there are some issue with this and hanging up in the production environment. But works fine in Test environment. All the setups are exactly same between Prod and Test. Any Idea guys?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look here:
http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx

I should add that if you remove / recreate the UPS it should re provision the FIM service.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with it not starting before, it was due an incorrect password enetered on the service account the UPS runs under.